# Polymorphic class member variable

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I have a class `messenger` which relies on a `printer` instance. `printer` is a polymorphic base class and the actual object is passed to the `messenger` in the constructor.

For a non-polymorphic object, I would just do the following:

```
class messenger {
public:
    messenger(printer const& pp) : pp(pp) { }

    void signal(std::string const& msg) {
        pp.write(msg);
    }

private:
    printer pp;
};
```

But when `printer` is a polymorphic base class, this no longer works (slicing).

What is the best way to make this work, considering that

1. I don’t want to pass a pointer to the constructor, and
2. The `printer` class shouldn’t need a virtual `clone` method (= needs to rely on copy construction).

I don’t want to pass a pointer to the constructor because the rest of the API is working with real objects, not pointers and it would be confusing / inconsistent to have a pointer as an argument here.

Under C++0x, I could perhaps use a `unique_ptr`, together with a template constructor:

```
struct printer {
    virtual void write(std::string const&) const = 0;
    virtual ~printer() { } // Not actually necessary …
};

struct console_printer : public printer {
    void write(std::string const& msg) const {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    }
};

class messenger {
public:
    template <typename TPrinter>
    messenger(TPrinter const& pp) : pp(new TPrinter(pp)) { }

    void signal(std::string const& msg) {
        pp->write(msg);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<printer> pp;
};

int main() {
    messenger m((console_printer())); // Extra parens to prevent MVP.

    m.signal("Hello");
}
```

Is this the best alternative? If so, what would be the best way in pre-0x? And is there any way to get rid of the completely unnecessary copy in the constructor? Unfortunately, moving the temporary doesn’t work here (right?).

Comment: Well, `unique_ptr` behaves for all practical purposes as pointer and the difference is lifecycle management.

Comment: +1 for `Extra parens to prevent MVP.` :D

Comment: btw. that constructor template may interfere with your copy constructor, at least I seem to remember Visual Studio complaining about it at some point...

Comment: Can you explain the `Extra parens to prevent MVP.`?

Comment: @Nim I’m not at all happy with the constructor template but this seems to be the only way if I want to pass an object rather than a pointer.

Comment: is the set of printers that are likely to exist within your control? Or is it an interface that the user could implement and pass into you? If the former, I would hold a variant of the types, if the latter, implement the constructor as above, but add a `disable_if` the passed in type is not derived from `printer`. Or alternatively if you can tightly couple the two, make `messenger` a template and avoid polymorphism altogether...

Comment: @Mark MVP = [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: @Nim If you add the `variant` / `disable_if` as an answer I can upvote it properly and it’s more visible for other people with similar problems. (And no, the set of implementations isn’t under my control).

Comment: why making `write` virtual if you are not using polimorphism?

Comment: @davka I *am* using polymorphism. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I misread your question. I though your goal was to avoid polimorphism, I see that you want to avoid using pointers. BTW: would using reference instead of pointer be better for you?

Comment: @davka As long as a reference *can* be used, that would be fine. But inside the class I need to take ownership of the object (see comment on gigantt’s answer) so references are out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to clone polymorphic object without a virtual clone method. So you can either:

- pass and hold a reference and ensure the printer is not destroyed before the messenger in the code constructing messenger,
- pass and hold a smart pointer and create the printer instance with new,
- pass a reference and create printer instance on the heap using clone method or
- pass a reference to actual type to a template and create instance with new while you still know the type.

The last is what you suggest with C++0x `std::unique_ptr`, but in this case C++03 `std::auto_ptr` would do you exactly the same service (i.e. you don't need to move it and they are otherwise the same).

Edit: Ok, um, one more way:

- Make the `printer` itself a smart pointer to the actual implementation. Than it's copyable and polymorphic at the same time at the cost of some complexity.

Comment: Hah, I had completely forgotten about `auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the comment into a proper answer...

The primary concern here is ownership. From you code, it is appears that each instance of `messenger` owns its own instance of printer - but infact you are passing in a pre-constructed printer (presumably with some additional state), which you need to then copy into your own instance of `printer`. Given the implied nature of the object `printer` (i.e. to print something), I would argue that the thing to which is it is printing is a shared resource - in that light, it makes no sense for each `messenger` instance to have it's own copy of `printer` (for example, what if you need to lock to access to `std::cout`)?

From a design point of view, what `messenger` needs on construction is actually really a pointer to some shared resource - in that light, a `shared_ptr` (better yet, a `weak_ptr`) is a better option.

Now if you don't want to use a `weak_ptr`, and you would rather store a reference, think about whether you can couple `messenger` to the type of `printer`, the coupling is left to the user, you don't care - of course the major drawback of this is that `messenger` will not be containable. NOTE: you can specify a traits (or policy) class which the `messenger` can be typed on and this provides the type information for printer (and can be controlled by the user).

A third alternative is if you have complete control over the set of printers, in which case hold a variant type - it's much cleaner IMHO and avoids polymorphism.

Finally, if you cannot couple, you cannot control the printers, and you want your own instance of `printer` (of the same type), the conversion constructor template is the way forward, however add a `disable_if` to prevent it being called incorrectly (i.e. as normal copy ctor).

All-in-all, I would treat the printer as a shared resource and hold a `weak_ptr` as frankly it allows better control of that *shared resource*.

Comment: Don’t get too hung up on semantics of the example identifiers, it was really hard to find a simple example that explains the problem. But in my real use-case the object is not a shared resource.

Comment: @Nim Which copy-ctor requirement? No, there are no shared resources at all.

Comment: @Konrad, I meant, why are you copy constructing? If there is nothing shared between instance of `printer`, why would you bother with the invoking the copy-ctor?

Comment: @Nim Where? In the construction of the smart pointer? How could I do this differently?

Comment: @Konrad, even in your simple example at the begining, you are invoking the copy-ctor for printer (to me that implies you are copying some *state* from the passed in printer to the instance of printer owned by `messenger`) And as for the construction of the smart pointer, again can't you just do `new TPrinter()`? Unless I'm missing something very obvious... (which could quite conceivably be the case)

Comment: @Nim In my simple example, what would have been the alternative to calling the constructor? After all, I’m *passing an object*. The same is true in my second example. Just because my objects don’t have shared state doesn’t mean that they have *no* state – they *do*.

Comment: @Konrad, I see, so you are passing in potentially the *initial state* via the copy-ctor. Okay fair enough, you know your situation better than me! :) I guess the only thing I'd say then is that what you have works, just add the `disable_if` just to disambiguate.

Answer (score 2):

```
Unfortunately, moving the temporary doesn’t work here (right?).
```

Wrong. To be, uh, blunt. This is what rvalue references are made for. A simple overload would quickly solve the problem at hand.

```
class messenger {
public:
    template <typename TPrinter>
    messenger(TPrinter const& pp) : pp(new TPrinter(pp)) { }
    template <typename TPrinter>
    messenger(TPrinter&& pp) : pp(new TPrinter(std::move(pp))) { }

    void signal(std::string const& msg) {
        pp->write(msg);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<printer> pp;
};
```

The same concept will apply in C++03, but swap `unique_ptr` for `auto_ptr` and ditch the rvalue reference overload.

In addition, you could consider some sort of "dummy" constructor for C++03 if you're OK with a little dodgy interface.

```
class messenger {
public:
    template <typename TPrinter>
    messenger(TPrinter const& pp) : pp(new TPrinter(pp)) { }
    template<typename TPrinter> messenger(const TPrinter& ref, int dummy) 
        : pp(new TPrinter()) 
    {
    }
    void signal(std::string const& msg) {
        pp->write(msg);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<printer> pp;
};
```

Or you could consider the same strategy that `auto_ptr` uses for "moving" in C++03. To be used with caution, for sure, but perfectly legal and doable. The trouble with that is that you're influencing all `printer` subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to pass a pointer or a smart pointer?

Anyway, if you're always initializing the printer member in the constructor you can just use a reference member.

```
private:
    printer& pp;
};
```

And initialize in the constructor initialization list.

Comment: This would result in a dangling reference as soon as `m` leaves the scope. As to why I don’t want to use a smart pointer – because it renders the API inconsistent (when does the user need to use an object, when a (smart) pointer?) and leaks implementation details.

Comment: either you want a copy of the printer object or not. Whatever makes sense. if you don't want a copy then aside from references and pointers there's not much you can do. I also don't see why using a smart pointer leaks implementation details..

Comment: @gigantt.com It leaks implementation details because the user doesn’t care what the class does internally with the object (and that might even be subject to change). All it cares about is that the class needs an instance of such an object. Whether this is transient (and hence only requires a reference) or stored shouldn’t matter. But I’m beginning to realize that resource ownership will *always* leak information, no matter what.

Comment: what's the significance of this supposed leak? The user doesn't know whether the class is actually storing a pointer or not. All it knows is that it has to be given a polymorphic item, and in C++ this is achieved with ptrs/refs... I fail to see the problem.

Comment: @gigantt Again, the user doesn’t care about pointers or references. The user doesn’t even care about polymorphism. From his point of view, an object is passed into the constructor. And polymorphism doesn’t require pointers either, references work just fine – but only as long as you don’t take over ownership of an object.

Comment: @Konrad: "The user doesn’t even care about polymorphism" - I seem to disagree. The server accept an interface, and the user is free to provide any custom implementation of that interface - this is a part of the contract so the user is well aware of that. And as for ref vs. ptr, I think (as you say) that it is a way to signal what ownership model is employed by the **server class**. This too must be made explicit to the user, so it's also part of the contract

Answer (score 1):

*When you have a golden hammer everything looks like nails*

Well, my latest golden hammer is *type erasure*. Seriously I would not use it, but then again, I would pass a pointer and have the caller create and inject the dependency.

```
struct printer_iface {
   virtual void print( text const & ) = 0;
};

class printer_erasure {
   std::shared_ptr<printer_iface> printer;
public:
   template <typename PrinterT>
   printer_erasure( PrinterT p ) : printer( new PrinterT(p) ) {}

   void print( text const & t ) {
      printer->print( t );
   }
};

class messenger {
   printer_erasure printer;
public:
   messenger( printer_erasure p ) : printer(p) {}
...
};
```

Ok, arguably this and the solutions provided with a template are the exact same thing, with the only slight difference that the complexity of type erasure is *moved* outside of the class. The `messenger` class has its own responsibilities, and the type erasure is not one of them, it can be delegated.

Answer (score 0):

How about templatizing the `class messanger` ?

```
template <typename TPrinter>
class messenger {
public:
    messenger(TPrinter const& obj) : pp(obj) { }
    static void signal(printer &pp, std::string const& msg) //<-- static
    {
        pp->write(msg);
    }
private:
    TPrinter pp;  // data type should be template
};
```

Note that, `signal()` is made `static`. This is to leverage the `virtual` ability of `class printer` and to avoid generating a new copy of `signal()`. The only effort you have to make is, call the function like,

```
signal(this->pp, "abc");
```

Suppose you have other datatypes then `pp` which are not related to template type, then those can be moved to a non template base class and that base can be inherited by `messenger`. I am not describing in much details but, I wish the point should be clearer.

Comment: Not possible in my context. And actually, if that were possible then the whole problem wouldn’t arise. I also don’t understand the usefulness of having `signal` static: if I’m using templates anyway I wouldn’t care about virtual functions and dynamic dispatch any more.

Comment: @Konrad, having `static signal()` was to not generate many copies of `signal` as there will not be any dependency on `template` param. Also to use `pp` inside `signal()` you have to pass it. However, since using `template` is not possible, this approach is of no use.